# PHP Application is broken on latest version of IIS10 and windows server 2019

Tags: php, html, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2019

I was trying running php application on php5.6 with latest server installation with IIS10, Windows Server 2019 and FastCGI.
But Application UI looks distorted (on php file with mixed html and php code).
Is that because of Latest version of iis and server OR Some PHP setting issue?
below is the sample code with error in console i'm getting.

this is the problem where DOCTYPE html has started with inside input placeholder

[image]

Sample Code -

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) && $_SESSION["mypassword"]){
        echo "<script>var token = localStorage.getItem('reccoon_usersid'); window.location.href='checklogin.php?user_session=' + token;</script>";
        // header("location:checklogin.php?");
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Reccoon::ViDoc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapjs/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="bootstrapjs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrapjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- Some css style here -->
    </style>      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">                                
                        <div class="row-fluid user-row">
                            <img src="images/reccoonlogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Conxole Admin"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="panel-login">
                                    <input id="user_session_id" type="hidden" name="user_session" value="">
                                    <div class="login_result"></div>
                                </label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="myusername" name="myusername">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="mypassword" name="mypassword">

                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                            </fieldset>
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($_SESSION['login_display_msg'])){           
                                        echo "<p id='display_login_validation'>".$_SESSION['login_display_msg']."</p>";
                                    }
                                    unset($_SESSION['login_display_msg']);
                                ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         if(localStorage.getItem('reccoon_usersid') !== undefined){
            $('#user_session_id').val(localStorage.getItem('reccoon_usersid'));
         }
    </script>  
</footer>
</html>
```

will be Appreciate if anyone can help with this crazy errors

Comment: did you make any changes in your php.ini file? which iis feature you enabled? did you make any changes in your CSS file? also, enable a detailed error message and check which status code you get. I tried your code but it does not reproduce the issue [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCc2p.png).